# Foreach insert multiple rows to database

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, insert, rows

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into my database by foreach. I have read a lot of questions and answers, but don't seem to get very close to finding a solution.

Here is my code:

```
       foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
        $product = $val['item_name'];
        $code = $val['item_code'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orderitems(product, code)VALUES('$product', '$code');";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
      }
```

This inserts several empty rows as well as a row with the first letter from the submit button. No matter what I do never manage to insert more than the last entry. I have a few more fields than just the two, so I presume those are the ones that get inserted blank.

And here is some code in my form:

```
  $cart_items = 0;
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product.'" />';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
  $cart_items ++;
```

I'd really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And as your code snippet is written, you're using the WRONG keys/vals in your foreach loop.

The form will be producing the following keys:

```
item_name[0] -> $obj->product
item_code[0] -> $product_code
```

And your foreach:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
```

would give `item_name` and `item_code` as the keys, and `$val` be an ARRAY of the values for each of those names. When you do your `$product` and `$code assignments, you're accessing array keys which don't exist.

You want this instead:

```
foreach($_POST['item_name'] as $key => $product) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^                      
    $name = $_POST['item_code'][$key];
    ... query goes here ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! However when I do this, nothing is being inserted in the database at all.

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($sql)` and see what the queries you're building look like. `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's coming in from the forms.

Comment: The SQL is completely empty, and the form sends only the latest product. But I don't really know why I'll be honest!